# How to tightly wrap a div around an image, but also resize the image to fit a content area if resolution is larger than content area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build an image viewer with specific requirements. They are as follows:

- The content area is a grid-area.
- If the image is larger than the content area, it should be contained without stretching the image.
- If the image is smaller than the content area, it should be centred within the content area.
- There must be a div tightly wrapping the image at all times.

I've made a quick sketch below illustrating the desired behaviour for a portrait (top row), and landscape (bottom row). The images on the left column are the behaviour required if the image's resolution is higher than the content area.

Color code:

- White box: content area.
- Red box: image.
- Blue border: image
  wrapping div.

[image: Requirements]

My primary approach so far has been to absolutely position the wrapping div around the image, which works fine until I try to get the resize to fit behaviour in. Usually this will break the tightly wrapped div.

I can also use Javascript, but because this is a foundation to build more on top of I'd rather try keep it to HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ensure that your div just assumes the size of the content, the `img` in this case. So don't use absolute. You mentioned using `grid`, so the below example will generate the a grid with a main section wrapped by `20px` padding. Then just use the `max` value on the img to make sure it does exceed the grid box's size. Then center it within the grid box:

```js
const width = document.querySelector( '[name=width]' );
const height = document.querySelector( '[name=height]' );
const image = document.querySelector( 'img' );

function onchange(){
  
  image.src = `http://placehold.it/${width.value}x${height.value}`;
  image.style = '';
  
}

width.addEventListener( 'change', onchange );
height.addEventListener( 'change', onchange );

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => setTimeout( onchange, 100 ) );
```

```css
body, html { height: 100%; }
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "left top right" 20px "left main right" 1fr "left bottom right" 20px / 20px 1fr 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
main div {
  grid-area: main;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
main div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#inputs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform .4s;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
body:hover #inputs {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <img />
  </div>
</main>

<div id="inputs">
  <label>Width: <input name="width" value="200" type="number" /></label>
  <label>Height: <input name="height" value="200" type="number" /></label>
</div>
```

I have included some javascript so you can test out different sizes of image. I added a `img.style = ''` to trigger a CSS recalculate after adding the new image, otherwise its size will be incorrect on load.